# Sorting of hash set in descending

Tags: java, sorting

I want to sort hashset values in descending value on the basis of length of string in hash set.

```
HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
hs.add("The World Tourism Organization");
hs.add("reports the following ten countries");
hs.add("as the most visited in terms of the number");
hs.add("of international travellers.");
System.out.println(hs);
```

My output should be

```
['as the most visited in terms of the number',
 'reports the following ten countries',
 'The World Tourism Organization',
 'of international travellers.']
```

What is the method to sort in descending order?

Answer (score 2):

A HashSet by definition doesn't sort its members. What you want is a TreeSet.

If you have a hashset you can create a treeset from it, as long as the objects are Comparable:

> TreeSet ts = new TreeSet (hs);

Answer (score 2):

You should use TreeSet instead of hashset or create a comparator to sort your set

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a `TreeSet` instead of a `HashSet` with your own custom comparator which will sort the values based on their lengths.

```
Set<String> yourSet = new TreeSet<>(new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        // Your comparison logic goes here
        return 0;
    }
});

// Add all the HashSet values to the TreeSet
yourSet.addAll(hs);
```

Answer (score 0):

`HashSet` does not provide any meaningful order to the entries. The documentation says:

It makes no guarantees as to the iteration order of the set; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time.

To get a sensible ordering, you need to use a different Set implementation such as `TreeSet`. `TreeSet` lets you provide a `Comparator` that specifies how to order the entries; something like:

```
public class SortByString implements Comparator<FullName>{
    public int compare(FullName n1, FullName n2) {
        return n1.getLastName().compareTo(n2.getLastName());
    }
}
```